# Adding a module dependency in Aurelia with Webpack

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I'm just getting started with the [Aurelia Webpack Skeleton](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-es2016-webpack) and trying to simply add a new dependency. Suppose I want to use moment.js in my application. What are the expected steps to download and use the module in my application?

EDIT: I see that moment.js is already loaded by default. So suppose it's numeral.js I want to use as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the library via npm using a console, pointing to the application folder:

```
npm install numeral --save
```

Now, you just have to import it in your js file:

```
import numeral from 'numeral';
```

Comment: OK I feel stupid for not trying that before asking. But I was expecting I'd need to added the package to a "config.js" ala JSPM. This might be too easy.

Comment: Yeah, easier than JSPM, and don't worry, it happens to everyone :)

Comment: Well, this works for the simple scenario I listed in my question, but for something more complicated like 'aurelia-dialog' more configuration is required. Anyone who finds this may want to see a related discussion here: https://github.com/aurelia/dialog/issues/126