# Cannot find module 'jquery-ui' when using Aurelia with Webpack

Tags: jquery-ui, typescript, webpack, aurelia

Im trying to get a simple datepicker to work in aurelia but I think I have missed something really basic here.

Im using the aurelia skeleton with webpack here

https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript-webpack

After this I assume its installing Jquery-ui that is next.

http://ilikekillnerds.com/2016/02/using-jquery-ui-widgets-in-aurelia/

Looking here it all seems simple. But no matter what I do I keep getting 
"[ts] Cannot find module 'jquery-ui'" on this row

```
import { datepicker } from "jquery-ui";
```

I cant figure out how to get the module working correctly.

```
npm install jquery
npm install jquery-ui 
tsd install jquery
tsd install jqueryui
```

Anything else missing here?

Since I use webpack I dont need any jspm magic? Or so I thought?

Edit:
[Adding a module dependency in Aurelia with Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579305/adding-a-module-dependency-in-aurelia-with-webpack)

Here it looks like

```
npm install jquery-ui --save
```

is all I need. Still same problem

Edit: Complete datepicker.ts code

```
import { customElement, bindable, inject } from "aurelia-framework";

import "jquery";
import { datepicker } from "jquery-ui";

@customElement('jquery-ui-datepicker')
@inject(Element)
export class JqueryUiDatepicker {
    @bindable id = '';
    @bindable name = '';
    @bindable options = {};

    constructor(Element) {
        this.element = Element;

        if (!this.id && this.name) {
            this.id = this.name;
        }

        if (!this.name && this.id) {
            this.name = this.id;
        }
    }

    attached() {
        $(`#${this.id}`).datepicker(this.options)
            .on('change', e => {
                let changeEvent = new CustomEvent('input', {
                    detail: {
                        value: e.val
                    },
                    bubbles: true
                });

                this.element.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
            });
    }

    detached() {
        $(`#${this.id}`).datepicker('destroy').off('change');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what the issue is but it might be worth switching to typings as tsd has been depricated https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/issues/269

Comment: looking at this it seems like I only should run "typings install" after npm install jquery-ui. But still same result :/ 

But i had both typings and tsd.. will remove tsd and see if this helps anything.

Comment: try this `import from "jquery-ui/datepicker"`

Comment: Still same. Whats even more annoying is that i can clearly see that jquery-ui is installed in my node_modules folder.

Comment: hmm ok. Show all view mode code, please.

Comment: Added code for datepicker.ts. Maybe worth mentioning is that I have a clean aurelia project. I cloned mentioned skeleton. Ran the commands (npm install / typings install). Added this file + everything in my power to add the module... Nothing else.

Comment: The `{ datepicker }` part of the import statement is not really necessary, since jquery-ui does not export anything as far as I know. Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: import "jquery-ui"; does not give my any errors. You might be onto something here

Comment: ok, but the datepicker is not showing up, right? you probably have to load some css files manually

Comment: like this `import "../node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css";`

Comment: You are the correct, sir. I can't get anything to show. Right now im back to just get a simple date picker work in aurelia without templating. Soon my monitor goes out the window and Im back to angular.

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Can't get any simpler than this?.. Still cant get it to work.

Comment: Holy smoke. Got something going now. Thanks for all the help. If you want to you can add the comment i upvoted as an answer and ill mark it for you.

Comment: Sure, I will. You are welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since jquery-ui does not export anything, you just have to import it, without loading any object or functions.

So, replace this:

```
import { datepicker } from "jquery-ui";
```

For this:

```
import "jquery-ui";
//if you want to load only the datepicker, use "jquery-ui/datepicker";
```

Now you would be able to use jquery-ui extension functions, like $.datepicker, $.accordion, etc.

However, there is another problem. Differently from SystemJS, webpack does not seem to load css files automatically, unless if it is explicitly loaded in the modules files.

For this reason, you have to load the css files as well. Like this:

```
import "../node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
//if you want to load only the datepicker, use "../node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css"
```

In short, this is what you need:

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "jquery-ui";
import "../node_modules/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css";
```

Webpack will bundle all the referenced css into one file, it means that referencing "node_modules" folder inside your project is not a big a deal because you will not have to create this folder in the production environment.

If jquery-ui is used throughout the application, it is a good candidate to be loaded in the main.js or app.js file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Did you manage to this working with the aurelia.json file?

What should i put in the main property as there is not a single/combined file in the node_modules/jquery-ui directory?

`{ 
        "name": "jquery-ui", 
        "path": "../node_modules/jquery-ui", 
        "main": "ui/core.js", 
        "deps": ["jquery"], 
        "resources": ["themes/base/all.css"]
    }`

Apologies for the formatting but i have no idea how to do a mini-markdown multi line code section

Comment: @alexs See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837505/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-aurelia