# How to use JQuery-UI with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I started a new Aurelia app using the Aurelia CLI.

I installed JQuery and configured aurelia.json using the instructions at the Aurelia documentation:

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/the-aurelia-cli/6

I then npm installed Jquery-ui.

I now need to know how to configure audelia.json to recognize jquery-ui.

In the Aurelia documentation this example is given on how to reference a module:

```
"dependencies": [
  {
    "name": "library-name",
    "path": "../node_modules/library-name/dist/library-name"
  }
]
```

The problem is that unlike when you download jquery-ui directly, the JQuery-ui module does not have an actual Jquery-ui.js file ( if it does I couldn't find it).

Thank you

Comment: That module reference syntax is for a single file module, but jQuery UI has multiple files. You'll probably need to use `main` to define main module file, in addition to `name` and `path`. Scroll a bit down in Aurelia doc sample you have posted, and you'll find samples for using `main` under "A CommonJS Package" and "A Legacy Library".

Comment: I know but it still doesn't answer the question of exactly how to do it

Comment: I tried to install this today also and wasn't able to get it to work.  I'd be interested in the solution.

Comment: I'm stuck on this too.  I had jquery-ui working with jspm, but haven't gotten in to work with cli yet.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Aurelia newbie here but see my answer below and see if it helps...

Answer (score 3):

The `jquery-ui` package doesn't include a "built" version of jquery-ui as far as I can tell. I finally got this working by using the `jquery-ui-dist` package, which includes the default jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.css files.

```
npm install jquery-ui-dist --save
```

Now add it aurelia.json in dependencies for vendor-bundle:

```
    "dependencies": [
      "aurelia-binding",
      ...
      "jquery",
      {
        "name": "jquery-ui-dist",
        "path": "../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist",
        "main": "jquery-ui",
        "deps": ["jquery"],
        "resources": [
          "jquery-ui.css"
        ]
      },
    ]
```

Notice we are loading jquery first. The "main" attribute tells it that it should load jquery-ui.js from that directory. The "deps" attribute tells it that it is dependent on jquery. Finally the "resources" attribute includes the default jquery-ui.css.

Now in app.html, be sure to require the css file:

```
<require from="jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.css"></require>
```

To use in a ts file:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui-dist';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Aurelia 1.0.X, after updating I needed these two imports for using any jQuery-UI widget, in this case draggable. It also works when importing slider or resizable.

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import {draggable} from 'jquery-ui';
```

In my package.json, my jspm dependencies are as follows:

```
"jquery": "npm:jquery@^3.2.1",
"jquery-ui": "github:components/jqueryui@^1.12.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add of copy of jquery-ui.js to your static folder and add this line to your constructor to the class you intend to use jquery-ui, Please note : it should  reference to the location of your jquery-ui file

```
import { $ } from 'jquery';
export class Index
{
  constructor(){
    require('../../../../../static/assets/js/jquery-ui');
  }
}
```